# Why does the RES keep growing slowly?

Tags: c++, memory-leaks

I have written a simple program to watch VIRT and RES change in top command. I'm curious about why does the RES keep growing slowly.

The program is running in the following system:

```
NAME="CentOS Linux"  
VERSION="7 (Core)"  
ID="centos"  
ID_LIKE="rhel fedora"  
VERSION_ID="7"  
PRETTY_NAME="CentOS Linux 7 (Core)"  
ANSI_COLOR="0;31"  
...
```

Here is the program code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstring>
#include <unistd.h>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  srand(time(nullptr));
  while (true) {
    int num = rand();
    int size = 0;
    if (num % 3 == 0) {
      size = rand() % (1024 * 1024 * 500) + 1;
    } else if (num % 3 == 1) {
      size = rand() % (1024 * 1024) + 1;
    } else {
      size = rand() % 1024 + 1;
    }
    char* mem = (char*)malloc(size);
    cout << "malloc " << size << endl;
    sleep(1);
    int use = max(rand() % size, 1);
    memset(mem, 1, use);
    cout << "use " << use << endl;
    sleep(1);
    free(mem);
    cout << "free " << size << endl;
    sleep(1);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

VIRT    RES(KB)
47476 33840
47476 33856
47476 33868
47476 33872
47476 33896
47476 33900

As we can see, the RES(after call free) keeps growing slowly, why?

Plus: I'm worry about that it keeps growing all the time, and finally exhausts the system's memory, although it may take many years.

Comment: There is no guarantee that `free` causes the OS to take back the memory immediately.

Comment: I'm not sure this can be answered; an implementation might make an allocation on a new page by default and garbage collect after a certain time, or if your random numbers start off low larger allocations will need a new page, or it might allocate a new page if there isn't a free one not more than x% larger than requested, etc.

Comment: @KenY-N, I'm worry about that it keeps growing all the time, and finally exhausts the system's memory, although it may take many years.

Comment: Thanks for god, the RES is stable at 34056 !